# XML Feed vs API Integration

Tags: xml

I am a novice programmer so I wasn't sure where to post this or ask this question. I wanted to know what the difference between an XML feed versus an API Integration is?

I thought some APIs come in the form in XML, so what's the difference between an API XML Integration and just an XML Feed?

If I wanted to update my data every 24 hours, can an XML feed and/or API do this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping in mind that naming things is hard and people often get fuzzy on such things.

A **feed** is generally a one-way street. A provider has some data that they make available at a URL and it gets updated when new data is available.

An **API** is generally a two-way street. You can usually expect to be able to do one or more of:

- Query / Filter / Search the data
- Drill down into related data (e.g. from a list of people you can get information that lets you get more information about a specific person)
- Add new data